# How do I show the number keyboard on an EditText in android?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I just basically want to switch to the number pad mode as soon a certain EditText has the focus.

Comment: The question does not specifically state a desire to change the allowed input type.  It simply asks how to change the keyboard mode which is what I would like to do without changing the input type.  All answers explain how to change the input type.

Comment: Check my answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39593324/cannot-resolve-symbol-showsoftinput/39593871#39593871

Answer (score 277, accepted):

You can configure an [`inputType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#Searchable_inputType) for your [`EditText`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html):

```
<EditText android:inputType="number" ... />
```

Comment: Also note that you need to target Android 1.5 to use this (it's not available in 1.1)

Comment: The problem is that you can't switch back. Using "number|text" does not work either. It seems if you want to show a numeric keyboard, you can't allow it switch back to text.

Comment: I agree with Brian..if the first field is alpha and next field is numeric, I cannot go to the next field using the 'Next' button!

Comment: Whether you can go back or not depends on the phone I think. Mine allows it.

Comment: I want to change keybord type number and I want paste text in edittext. How to do?

Answer (score 114):

To do it in a Java file:

```
EditText input = new EditText(this);
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Answer (score 56):

I found this implementation useful, shows a better keyboard and limits input chars.

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:digits="1234567890"
    ...
/>
```

Additionally, you could use `android:maxLength` to limit the max amount of numbers.

To do this programmatically:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);

KeyListener keyListener = DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("1234567890");
editText.setKeyListener(keyListener);
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this programmatically? Dying to get a limited number keyboard for my EditText but it's set up in such a way it has to be generated in the activity.

Answer (score 19):

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
    android:inputType="number|phone"/>
```

will show the large number pad as dialer.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it 2 ways

1. Runtime set

   ```
   EditText input = new EditText(this);
   input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
   ```
2. Using XML

   ```xml
   <EditText
       ...
       android:inputType="number" />
   ```

Answer (score 8):

If you need fractional number, then this is the answer for you:

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using your EditText in Dialog or creating dynamically and You can't set it from xml then this example will help you in setting that type of key board while you are using dynamic Edit Text etc

```
myEditTxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

where myEditTxt is the dynamic EDIT TEXT object(name)

Answer (score 4):

```
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Comment: If you are manually formatting a text (like for currency) and want to control just the keyboard, that's the choice. Won't filter your chars. Thanks!

Comment: This worked like a charm for me. I want to display a textual placeholder value when a field has not been edited yet, but still restrict the input to numbers and display a restricted keyboard.

Answer (score 4):

Use the below code in java file

> editText.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_QWERTY);

Comment: you have the best answer!! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Below code will only allow numbers "0123456789”, even if you accidentally type other than "0123456789”, edit text will not accept.

```
    EditText number1 = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.edittext); 
    number1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER|InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
    number1.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789”));
```

Comment: You should add commentary explaining your code and why it is the solution

Answer (score 2):

More input types and details found [here](http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html) on google website

Answer (score 1):

Define this in your xml code

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText number1 = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.edittext); 
number1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Comment: If you have EditText number1 created in layout xml code, then if you want to set Number Keyboard to number1 EditText, you can do this way using Java Code.