# Android EditText numeric keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext

This is my EditText xml code:

```
  <EditText
   android:layout_width="200dp"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:inputType="number"/>
```

There are 20 EditText's in my xml. When I touch any of the EditText for the first time (after Activity is created), full keyboard (with letters) appears. Next time, when I touch some EditText numeric keboard appears (which is correct).

How to display numeric keyboard also when activity is created on first time and EditText is touched on first time?

FYI: I am using Android 5.1

Comment: if you try digits:"1234567890"

Comment: check with here link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119583/how-do-i-show-the-number-keyboard-on-an-edittext-in-android

Comment: don't you have any specific code which changes input type?

Comment: try using android:inputType = "phone"

Comment: Tried inputType = phone, = numberDecimal - nothing changed. I tried on another phone and it is the same. Is it bug in Android or Xamarin.Android (I use it)? I don't handle EditTexts in my code behind.

Comment: I noticed that when I touch EditText for first time, numeric keyboard blinks for a while (100 ms or so), then full keyboard appears. After that, when touching any other EditText numeric keyboard appears always.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will work

```
<EditText
android:digits="0123456789."
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
/>
```

**OR**

```
android:inputType="phone"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119583/how-do-i-show-the-number-keyboard-on-an-edittext-in-android